# attempted to perform an unauthorized operation in event log of remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authorization, event-log

When I am executing the following code to the local machine, it works fine:

```
string eventLogName = "Security";
string sourceName = "BTHUSB";
string machineName = "Venus";
EventLog eventLog;
eventLog = new EventLog();
eventLog.Log = eventLogName;
eventLog.Source = sourceName;
eventLog.MachineName = machineName;

foreach (EventLogEntry e in eventLog.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entry type :{0}",e.EntryType);
}
```

When I am executing above code it does not execute it gives an error as:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code under a user who has local admin permissions on remote machine.

Comment: I tend to develop software on my host as an ordinary user so that I can detect this issues immediately.